# VS2008: Copy Web Site from command line

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, command-line

How do I execute the "Copy Web Site" command for an ASP.NET project in VS2008 from the command line? If I need to script this, let me have some pointers on where I can learn that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would this help you get started?

[Walkthrough: Deploying an ASP.NET Web Application Using XCOPY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f735abw9.aspx)